# Representing a Binary Tree in a file

Tags: algorithm, file, data-structures, tree

What are the different strategies involved in representing Binary tree in a file so that the tree structure can be recreated easily?I am using C.

Comment: I think your question is too vague. In Java I guess you could use `Serializable`.

Comment: Question is quite ambiguous, can you be more precise!

Comment: I will be creating a binary tree using a c program and I need to store the tree structure on to a file so that I can recreate the tree again some other time by reading from the file.

Comment: @PaulDC You can store the tree as (value, leftsubtree, rightsubtree) format. Eg. (1, (2, (4, NULL, NULL), (5, NULL, NULL)), (3, (6, NULL, NULL), (7, NULL, NULL))) to store a simple tree that has 1 as root, 2&3 as second level nodes and 4,5,6&7 as leaves. It is O(n) to write and O(n) to read the tree. Let me know if you need the complete algorithm.

Comment: @ElKamina A variation on this representation is to remove trailing NULL values from the triplets. Your sample tree could then be written (1, (2, (4), (5)), (3, (6), (7))). (Only trailing NULLs can be removed; if a node had a NULL left subtree but a non-NULL right subtree, it would have to be represented as (value, NULL, rightsubtree).)

Comment: @TedHopp Yes. That is right. Another option is to do a traversal and keep track of backtracks. For the same tree, you can store it as 1,2,4,NULL,NULL,5,NULL,NULL,3,6,NULL,NULL,7,NULL,NULL .

Comment: see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/339/152 for efficient representations.

Comment: I like the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Succinct_encodings. You would need to keep two arrays on disk, one for the structure and one for the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the inorder and preorder traversal of the tree in the file. Any binary tree can be reconstructed by inorder and preorder traversals[1].

[1] http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/

Answer (score 1):

You will need atleast 2 traversals of the tree in order to be able to construct the exact tree.Because there can be more than one unique tree possible from one given traversal.

For example -you can store the inorder and preorder traversals of a binary tree into your text file and follow the below link to work it out from there while recreating the tree.

http://leetcode.com/2011/04/construct-binary-tree-from-inorder-and-preorder-postorder-traversal.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive way, assuming you have something like:

```
struct bst {
   int val;
   struct bst *left; // NULL when no node
   struct bst *right;
}
```

Make another struct like so:

```
struct bst_serial {
   int val;
   int left; // NULL when no node
   int right;
}
```

Then, malloc an array of `bst_serial`s that is as large as your tree:

```
struct bst_serial *serial_bst = malloc(sizeof(struct bst_serial) * tree_size);
```

Now, do a traversal of the tree like so (untested):

```
int current_pos = 0;

int convert_node(bst *root) {
    int this_pos = current_pos;
    current_pos++;        

    serial_bst[this_pos].val = root->val;
    if(root->left != NULL) {
       serial_bst[this_pos].left = convert_node(root->left);
    } else {
       serial_bst[this_pos].left = -1;
    } 

    if(root->right != NULL) {    
       serial_bst[this_pos].right = convert_node(root->right);
    } else {
       serial_bst[this_pos].right = -1;
    } 
    return this_pos;
}
```

You can now `write()` the array out to disk. If you write functions to traverse the `bst_serial` type of tree, then you don't even need to deserialise it - you can just `mmap()` it. For extra points, don't even use the pointer tree in the first place - create and grow the `bst_serial` array as you create the binary tree. Then your code doesn't need to care whether it's dealing with a tree from disk or a tree you've just created.

Answer (score -1):

Do an in-order traversal, and write the value of the node to the file delimeted with new lines. If a node is a leaf store a special character (e.g. #) after the leaf value.

When you read the file, until you don't get a '#' insert values, and descend to the left. If you get '#' ascend until there are no elements to the right, and descend to right. Do this recursively.

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't preserve your original tree. It would preserve only a correct binary seach tree with the same numbers.

Comment: By descend to left you mean, attach a child to the left, right? Then what do you mean by ascend?

Comment: If a node has no right-child this would not work. You need to put extra # for this case.